# Send audio to remote device via https using Gstreamer

Tags: audio, https, gstreamer

Is there a way to send an audio via https using GStreamer? I've written a code sample but I don't know how to synchronize keys between client and server. My client generate a key in order to encode the data. But audio receiver actually doesn't have any keys.

```
                gst_init(NULL, NULL);
                std::random_device rd;
                std::mt19937 gen(rd());
                std::uniform_int_distribution<unsigned int> dis(0, 255);

                srtpenc = gst_element_factory_make("srtpenc", "srtp-encryption");
                pipeline = gst_pipeline_new("audio-rtsp-pipeline");
                audioconvert = gst_element_factory_make("audioconvert", "audio-convert");
                audiosink = gst_element_factory_make("udpsink", "udp-sink");
                appsrc = gst_element_factory_make("appsrc", "audio-source");

                g_object_set(G_OBJECT(appsrc), "block", TRUE, NULL);
                g_object_set(G_OBJECT(appsrc), "format", GST_FORMAT_TIME, NULL);

                gst_bin_add(GST_BIN(pipeline), appsrc);

                for (int i = 0; i < 16; ++i) {
                    key[i] = static_cast<unsigned char>(dis(gen));
                }

            g_object_set(srtpenc, "key", key, NULL);


            if (!pipeline || !appsrc || !audioconvert || !audiosink || !srtpenc) {
                return NC_COMMUNICATION_ERROR;
            }

            //  pipeline
            g_object_set(audiosink, "host", dottedIPAddress.c_str(), "port", pAudioOut->pTalkThread->GetClientPortNum(), NULL);
            g_object_set(audiosink, "sync", FALSE, NULL);

            gst_bin_add_many(GST_BIN(pipeline), appsrc, audioconvert, srtpenc, audiosink, NULL);
            gst_element_link_many(appsrc, audioconvert, srtpenc, audiosink, NULL);

            // start pipeline
            gst_element_set_state(pipeline, GST_STATE_PLAYING);
```